# How to implement 2 interdependent multi-select dropdown lists in Angular?

Tags: dropdown

I need to implement 2 interdependent multi-select dropdown lists in Angular. Selection from 1st dropdown filters values in 2nd dropdown and vice versa. Can anyone please share any reference for this?

Comment: Interdependent UI elements are almost always a bad idea. What is your use-case and why do you think its a good idea? Note that _cascading_ (unidirectional) drop-downs are fine (e.g. Country + State), but how should an interdependent dropdown UI work, exactly?

Comment: Also, what version of Angular are you using? Angular1/AngularJS, or something else? Are you using a state-management system like Reflux or Redux?